# How to save ListView position?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have custom **ListView** I just want to save scrolling position if the user want to go back to list view activity I tried a lot of answers here and none of them work for me. Here is my code.

```
    lst = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    customListview customListview = new customListview(this, storynum, 
    storynam, imag);
    lst.setAdapter(customListview);
```

**some of the answers that i tested**

```
    public void saveLastPosition() {
    int position = lst.getLastVisiblePosition();

    SharedPreferences pref = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putInt("lastPosition", position);
    editor.apply();
    }

     public void getLastPosition() {
    int position = lst.getLastVisiblePosition();

    SharedPreferences pref = 

   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int lastPosition = pref.getInt("lastPosition", position);
    lst.setSelection(lastPosition);
}
```

**this is the activity that the user will press the back button to go back to list view activity**

```
            case R.id.bar_back:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityS2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
```

## **Edit** logcat for this method

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ListView.getLastVisiblePosition()' on a null object reference
    at com.slltour.desar.qasharirh.ActivityS2.getLastPosition(ActivityS2.java:251)
    at com.slltour.desar.qasharirh.ActivityS2.onCreate(ActivityS2.java:52)
```

**And Thanks for any help**

Comment: you should set the position again

Comment: ya, getLastPosition()  set it onCreate my app crashes, I followed someone here but did not work .

Comment: post the crash log

Comment: Check the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a null value from getLastPosition becuase you're using it before initializing.

```
 lst.setAdapter(customListview);
 if(getLastPosition!=0)
 lst.smoothScrollToPosition(getLastPosition());
```

Modify your method like this

```
public int getLastPosition() {
SharedPreferences pref = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int lastPosition = pref.getInt("lastPosition", 0);
return lastPosition;
}
```

Comment: Hi again :(, The code works fine the issue is when i open listview activity for the first time it will jump to the middle of list view. Sorry still trying to learn :(

Comment: Before you close the app reset the value of preference to 0

Comment: the method work great just i think it save the position even if i quite the app, i need to destroy that activity list after i quite the app.

Comment: just set the preference to 0 before closing the app

Comment: how can i do that onBackprssed?

Comment: Thank u so much u helped me  a lot .best :)

Comment: Please Upvote the answer if it helped you, happy coding